# Where have I made a mistake?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spring

[image]

Question
 Find the period of oscillation of the above figure, assuming frictionless and massless pulley?

I figured the displacement from each side is the same thus $x(k_{1}+k_{2})=-ma$, after the equilibrium adjustment. Thus giving a time period of $2\pi \sqrt { \frac { m }{ { k }_{ 1 }+{ k }_{ 2 } }  } $, after plugging the given value i get a wrong answer, Where did i make a mistake?

Comment: you're saying you get the wrong answer, but what is the original question you are trying to answer?

Comment: much better now

Comment: I do not understand why this question was closed as "unclear". OP shows a diagram of a mechanical system; states his assumptions, and shows his solution. His solution is wrong, and he doesn't know where his mistake was - so he asks "where did I make a mistake?". There is sufficient information to see the mistake quite plainly. What clarification would you need - in other words, what would OP have to add/clarify for the question to be re-opened?

Comment: @Floris Note that I voted to close because it the kind of discouraged homework.

Comment: @Floris I suppose one could say the OP has to specify what conceptual problem he or she is having. But I agree the "unclear" close reason seems misapplied here. I would say it should have been put on hold using our dedicated homework close reason.

Comment: @DavidZ I was not aware there is a "close for reason of homework" reason. I thought OP had made a credible attempt - but overlooked the fact that pulley = equal force, not equal displacement. So he asked "where did I make a mistake" - which looked fair to me. Seemed like a reasonably interesting question (although not likely to be found by others with this problem). Well - today I learnt to create "hidden" equations...

Comment: @Floris It's not really closing just because it's homework; I only used that to refer to the close reason we have for questions which violate our [policy on homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714). You've probably seen this reason used on other questions; essentially it says that questions must ask about a specific physics concept and show sufficient effort toward obtaining the solution. If someone just asks us to check their work or where they made a mistake and that is the extent of the  question, that's against our policy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that there is a pulley. Your expression assumes that the two springs extend by the same amount - this would be the case if the pulley that the mass is attached to could not rotate. Therefore, you need to set the *force* on each side to the same value - this is different than the *displacement*.

Since this is homework, I will leave at that. Let me know if you need more after thinking about this more.

** update 1 **

If we write the extension of spring 1 as $x_1$ and spring 2 as $x_2$, then we have force balance when

$$ k_1 x_1 = k_2 x_2 $$

The total displacement of the mass is $(x_1 + x_2)/2$

Use these two expressions to come up with an "effective spring constant" (something that relates displacement to force (and the force is $k_1 x_1 + k_2 x_2$ of course).

**Update 2**
We need the "effective k" for the system - which is the change in force when we change the displacement. To get this value, we solve the following set of equations (**SPOILER ALERT**: when you hover over the yellow regions the solution is revealed)

> $$\begin{align} x &= \frac12 (x_1 + x_2) &(1)\\k_1 x_1 &= k_2x_2 &(2)\\F &= k_1x_1 + k_2x_2 &(3)\end{align}$$

From these three equation, we eliminate $x_1$ and $x_2$ to end up with a relationship of $F$, $k_1$, $k_2$ and $x$.

Substitute (2) into (1):

> $$\begin{align} x_2 &= \frac{k_1}{k_2}x_1 &(4)\\ x &= \frac12x_1 (1 + \frac{k_1}{k_2}) &(5) \end{align}$$

Substitute (2) into (3), then compute $F/x$ :

> $$\begin{align}F&=2k_1x_1\\\frac{F}{x}&=\frac{2k_1 x_1}{\frac12x_1 (1 + \frac{k_1}{k_2})}\\&=\frac{4 k_1 k_2}{k_1 + k_2}\end{align}$$

If that is the effective spring constant, then the period of the system should be

> $$T = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{m(k_1+k_2)}{4k_1k_2}} $$

Comment: i need a bit more than that?

Comment: @Derg - I have updated the answer. This is all you are going to get... please confirm that this matches "the answer" you were expecting.

Comment: Ok thanks, now i understand. One last question how do you make the question pop up when u scroll over them, that a cool feature? Could you pls share how you do it?

Comment: And yeah i checked it is a correct answer.

Comment: Glad to hear you confirm it's correct. As for the "special effect": When you add `>!` in front of your text (first two columns), it becomes like a block quote (which you get with just `>`), but with the roll over effect. For example, the third block was made with `>!$$\begin{align}F&=2k_1x_1\\\frac{F}{x}&=\frac{2k_1 x_1}{\frac12x_1 (1 + \frac{k_1}{k_2})}\\&=\frac{4 k_1 k_2}{k_1 + k_2}\end{align}$$`

Comment: Please don't post complete answers to homework-like questions in the future. I won't delete this because it's already been accepted though.

Comment: I didn't - originally. But my hint didn't suffice... Can you point me to the policy regarding homework on physics.SE - it is not uniform across SE sites and apparently I am not adhering by this community's standard for which I apologize.

Comment: This [meta.physics.se search query](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=homework+policy) should suffice to find the homework policy (note that some of the older posts might be outdated, so try looking at ones since October-ish and newer).